# group by a date range in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, date-range

I'm making a sheet in google Spreadsheet and I'd like some help with you. I want to group some values based on a date range (from 25/12/2015 to 25/01/2015, for example). The interval will be always from 25 of one month to 25 of the another. Is there anyway I could do this automatically? I already did it grouping by month, but could't in a date range.
This is an example sheet I'm working:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFEAalIo378Q3DVZ4aJKGCADy3dzjs8nJr5fm55eNvg/pubhtml

Tks!

Rafael.

Comment: Could you share the actual spreadsheet, so we can see the formulas?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19XzjRfRBCK6oYGP0lWI6ZE4kNmaNOE66LXBgRv6HSVw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the one I'm trying to edit is the sheet called "Modelo". The interval dates are different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

This spreadsheet groups data by date range:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SriUMoTOEHnyFDdG3DJHrzBZzLntShgeaGTQDhKTrfI/edit?usp=sharing

Just a simple filter command:

```
=FILTER(A2:B, B2:B>=E$1, B2:B<=E$2)

A2:B = the data
B2:B = the date column
E1 = the begin date
E2 = the end date
```

It looks like you are doing one long formula in your spreadsheet. I would suggest breaking it up into smaller pieces (at least for testing), if possible.